# if $ i:L^{p}( d\mu )\longrightarrow L^{q}(d\mu) $ is an inclusion map, then $ i $ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that if $ i:L^{p}( d\mu )\longrightarrow L^{q}(d\mu) $ is an inclusion map where $ (X,A, \mu) $ is a measure space and $L^{p}(d\mu)\subseteq L^{q}( d\mu ) $, then $ i $ is bounded.
Firstly, we can use the definition: For this I need to find constant $ c $ such that $ \parallel f \parallel_{L^{q}}<c\parallel f\parallel_{L^{p}} $ for all $ f\in L^{p} $. But I could not find this $ c $.
So ı tried to use closed graph theorem: Assume that $ f_{n} $ converges to $ f $ in $ L^{p} $ and $ i(f_{n})=f_{n} $ converges to $ g $ in $ L^{q} $. I need to show that $ f=g $. Since $ L^{q} $ is complete then $ g\in L^{q} $. If ı can show that $ f_{n} $ converges to $ g $ in $ L^{p} $, ı can conclude that $ f=g $. If measure of $ X $ is finite, I showed this. But I could not finish the question. if measure of $ X $ is not finite,how can we show that $ f_{n} $ converges to $ g $ in $ L^{p} $.

Comment: You're on the right track with the closed graph theorem. To finish your proof, use that every $L^p$-convergent sequence has an a.e. convergent subsequence. And please fix the sub- and superscripts in your Latex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convergence in any $L^{p}$ implies almost everywhere convergence for some subsequence. Hence $f_n \to f$ in $L^{p}$ and $f_n \to g$ in $L^{q}$ implies some subsequence converges a.e to both $f$ and $g$ which implies $f=g$ a.e..

(First choose  a subsequence which converges a.e. to $f$ and then choose  a further subsequence which converges a.e. to $g$)